# Autoresizing masks do not work programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

It is necessary to expand the `view` depending on the device, if the mask exhibit in the `storyboard` everything works.
[IMAGE STORYBOARD SETTINGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLPgE.png)

if use the programmatically:

```
viewTest.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

That the transition to SE for iPhone 7 view does not expand, I think the problem is that you have to ask where that is necessary to expand the SE, but here's how to do it do not know.

Comment: "That the transition to SE for iPhone 7 view does not expand" — How are you doing this transition? Normally this wouldn't be an issue on an actual device.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I use

```
view.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                          UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                          UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                          UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
                         );
```

and works like when i create view in storyboard and set the frame flexible.

I think because the system needs also the margins